# wrong p-value when calculating by stats.ttest_ind

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, p-value

I have tried to calculate the p-value of two pandas series- Ref_for_avg and CNOGA_for_avg. I also calculated the mean and std of both series. The mean and std calculations are correct, however for some reason the, p-value which is calculated on the same 2 series is not correct.

I have these messages when I run the program:

```
" RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  warnings.warn("Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice", RuntimeWarning)"
"RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars"
"RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)"
"RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)"
"RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
  cond2 = cond0 & (x <= self.a)"
```

this is a part from my code:

```
        for j_of_ErrDiffRange in ErrDiffRange_cols:
           if np.isinf(j_of_ErrDiffRange):
               ind_err = ErrDiff > ErrDiffRange_cols[-2]
           else:
               ind_err = ErrDiff <=j_of_ErrDiffRange

           inError_bool=ind_err
           Ref_inRange_bool=ind_err & ind_ref
           CNOGA_inRange_bool=ind_err & ind_CNOGA

           Ref_for_avg=Ref[Ref_inRange_bool]
           Ref_for_totalrow=Ref[inError_bool]

           CNOGA_for_avg=CNOGA[CNOGA_inRange_bool]
           CNOGA_for_totalrow=CNOGA[inError_bool]
           t, p_value= stats.ttest_ind(Ref_for_avg, CNOGA_for_avg, 
           equal_var=False)
           t_tot, p_value_tot= stats.ttest_ind(Ref_for_totalrow, 
           CNOGA_for_totalrow, equal_var=False)
```

Can you please help me to find the problem?

Thanks alot.

Comment: help ? someone? Thanks

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.